# How to cut a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, geoprocessing, open-source-gis, ogr

I want to use a shapefile of the [Corine Land Cover](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-1). This covers all of Europe, but I am only interested in the area of Scandinavia.

How can I cut this file using free software (preferably a command line tool)? I tried *ogr2ogr*

```
C:\Program Files\GDAL>ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" c:\Users\Christoph\geo\corine\clc06_c312_coniferous\clc06_c312_dalarna.shp c:\Users\Christoph\geo\corine\clc06_c312_coniferous\clc06_c312.shp -clipdst 0 60 20 70
```

but without any usable result (just almost empty files).

Comment: Have you got a vector data which is the border of your area of interest (Scandinavia)? If yes you can use a clip tool in Quantum gis (Vector->geometry tools).

Comment: Corine files are huge, I doubt ftools can handle them @com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the example at the bottom of the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) page, and note the "-t_srs EPSG:4326", which reprojects the file.  When I looked at a Corine .prj file just now, it was in ETRS_1989_LAEA_L52_M10 projection, which uses meters not degrees.  Once you reproject, I suspect your -clipdst settings will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL features of OGR and create a select query to extract only selected polygons. See [Link](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html)